# how to check html is valid or not in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, validation

Is there any way to check html validity in angular with pipe or function or npm package or API except regex?

I have tried it with `https://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=json` API but I think it is not giving correct result as I want. It is passed html even if I send html without closing tag like `<p>Hello There`

I have html code in one variable. Now I want to check whether that html is valid or not in angular.

Can you help me out? Thanks

Comment: Your question is based on a false promise. The end tag for the `<p>` element is optional, so omitting it is valid HTML.

Comment: Maybe this should help: https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator

Comment: @shadowman_93 — It won't. Expressing all the rules of HTML in a regex is impossible.

Comment: Ok Thanks Quentin